# Reset the undo stack in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, undo, ace-editor

I want to reset the undo stack in an [ACE editor](http://ace.c9.io/). The behavior should be:

1. I do some changes in editor.
2. Call some magic function to reset the undo stack
3. When trying to undo, this will not be possible because the undo stack was reset.

I guess it has to do with the [`UndoManager`](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=undomanager) from ACE, but I have no idea how can I use it in the following example.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/markdown");

setTimeout(function() { 
  editor.setValue("And now how can I reset the\nundo stack,so pressing\nCTRL+Z (or Command + Z) will *NOT*\ngo back to previous value?", -1);
}, 3000);
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor">This value will be changed in 3 seconds.</div>
```

I have looked into `editor` and `editor.session` prototypes to find some helper function, but without success.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, `UndoManager` is the class which maintains all the history. 
The solution is to initialize the session with a blank/newly created class.

Check out the snippet.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/markdown");

setTimeout(function() {
  editor.setValue("And now how can I reset the\nundo stack,so pressing\nCTRL+Z (or Command + Z) will *NOT*\ngo back to previous value?", -1);
  editor.getSession().setUndoManager(new ace.UndoManager())
}, 3000);
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor">This value will be changed in 3 seconds.</div>
```

Comment: But now I'm not able to CTRL + Z anything.

Comment: Yes, that was the requirement I guess ? or you just want to remove last change i..e which happened by JavaScript ? Please clarify...

Comment: I want to reset everything until that point, but after that I want to be able to use undo.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry my bad. I did deleted the UndoManager, but **forgot to initialize UndoManager with a new one**. Please check updated answer. Hope this helps...

Comment: Instead of creating a new undo manager you can just call the `getUndoManager().reset()` function.  As long as you do it inside the `setTimeout()` call, you get the same result.   Also, I set my timeout for `700` ms.

Comment: This is awesome. I am working on a project where I have multiple documents that I switch between in the same ace editor. Using `$.extend({}, getUndoManager())` I am able to save the current undo's. And then when fill the editor, I reset to a new undo manager, and if there is an existing undo manager on that document, I throw that in instead. Keeps my undo history across all documents without duplicating ace editors.

Answer (score 10):

use `editor.session.setValue()` or call `editor.session.getUndoManager().reset();` see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/lib/ace/edit_session.js#L279

Comment: Hmmm, I tried using the `reset()` method, but [it doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/q8x8p5nc/), why?

Comment: Because it looks like editor.session.getUndoManager() return a constructor for undoManger it returns the function:  
`function() {this.reset()}`

Comment: calling reset immediately doesn't work, because changes are added to undoManager after a timeout

Comment: I suggest a combination of the answers here: `setTimeout(function() { editor.getSession().getUndoManager().reset(); }, 700);`

Comment: Just use editor.session.setValue() and reset() will be called after values are set. So no need to use timers.